# How to send data from Arduino to Raspberry pi using ESP8266 Module

Tags: webserver, raspberry-pi3, arduino-uno

I need to send sensors (MPU9250) data from arduino to the Raspberry Pi 3, I'm thinking about using the ESP8266 Module in Arduino, but i can't find any help on how I will do this.

I'm thinking about creating a local web server using the ESP8266 and retrieve the data using a python script in the Raspberry Pi, but I am having trouble with the script for retrieve data from the server that is in another host.

Answer (score 2):

you could create a simple rest api by adapting this [tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/a-rest-api-for-arduino-and-the-cc3000-wifi-chip/application-a-basic-web-app) for your usecase. then use the python [requests libary](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/requests/using-requests-in-python) on the raspberry pi to poll the ardunio every x secconds